# How to access current element on event in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Code:

```
class Locations extends React.Component {
    render() {
        let { home, work, onChange } = this.props;
        return <div className="controls">

            <GoogleMapLoader
                containerElement={
                    <div
                        {...this.props}
                        style={{
                            height: '100%'
                        }} >
                    </div>
                }
                googleMapElement={
                    <GoogleMap
                        ref="map"
                        defaultZoom={15}
                        center={{
                            lat: 47.6205588,
                            lng: -122.3212725,
                        }}
                    >
                        <SearchBox
                            ref="searchBoxHome"
                            placeholder="Home"
                            controlPosition={google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT}
                            onPlacesChanged={onChange(this.refs.searchBoxHome.getPlaces(), 'home')}
                        />
                        ...
```

Error:

> TypeError: this.refs.searchBoxHome is undefined

I'm not sure how to properly bind the method on the element to the onChange function that I pass in.

Action:

```
export const changeAddress = (places, place) => {
    return {
        type: 'CHANGE_ADDRESS',
        places,
        place
    }
};
```

Comment: what should you pass to `onPlacesChanged`? Reference to function?

Comment: @Alexander onplaceschanged seems to call a function without passing arguments. Added my action

Comment: try do like this https://jsfiddle.net/nza3er61/ or just with arrow function https://jsfiddle.net/nza3er61/1/. Wrap your `onChange` to another

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `event` is passed by default to the function, which you can access the element by `event.target`.

```
onChange(element, home) {
  ...
}
```

and

```
<SearchBox
  ref="searchBoxHome"
  placeholder="Home"
  controlPosition={google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT}
  onPlacesChanged={event => onChange(event.target, 'home')}
/>
```

Comment: `onPlacesChanged={() => onChange(this.refs.searchBoxHome.getPlaces(), 'home')}`

Comment: @Tjorriemorrie could you explain your comment? It is right answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can try use [`arrow function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), like this

```
<SearchBox
  ref="searchBoxHome"
  placeholder="Home"
  controlPosition={ google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT }
  onPlacesChanged={
    () => onChange(this.refs.searchBoxHome.getPlaces(), 'home')
  }
/>
```